# I'm trying to move my edit button which is in a grid over

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

[image]

I'm trying to move the edit button I have over towards the grid and keep it responsive can anyone assist with this I cant figure it out? below is a link to my code.

https://ryanmexin.github.io/se_project_aroundtheus/

I've tried multiple different items. I'm not sure what to do at this point

Comment: Please include your code in the question itself, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example is a good resource

Answer (score 0):

I would've used bootstrap if I was you tbh, change **profile__paragraph** class to a **row** and put the title in **col-6** and the button in **col-6**, bootstrap saves you a lot of time and it's good for responsive design

Comment: Thank you! I would of but I had to create this on my own for a class.